# xslt transforms utf-8 characters to a different encoding

Tags: xslt

This problem is occurring intermittently, that is I have performed many xslt transformation without this problem, then it suddenly appeared during my latest xslt transformation.

I have a large number of html input files with a structure similar to the following a.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrd">
      <div class="wrd-id">5</div>
      <div class="wrd-wrd">address</div>
      <div class="wrd-ipa">əˈdres,ˈaˌdres</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I check the encoding of the input files I get the following result:

```
file -I a.html 
a.html: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I transform the html files with an xslt similar to the following a.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']" >
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use a script similar to the following a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc --html a.xslt a.html > b.html
```

A more complete bash script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc --html a.xslt a.html \
| hxnormalize -x -l 1024 \
| sed '/^$/d' \
> b.html
```

And I obtain the following result b.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrd">
      <div class="wrd-id">5</div>
      <div class="wrd-wrd">address</div>
      <div class="wrd-ipa">ÉËdres,ËaËdres</div>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In fact my output contains a few upside-down question marks that I cannot copy and paste here. Please see picture below

[image: non UTF-8 output]

The input characters that belong to the UTF-8 character set have been transformed into something else.

When I check the encoding of the file b.html I get the following result:

```
file -I b.html
b.html: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

How can I prevent an xslt transformation to change my characters from one encoding to another?

UPDATE 1

By removing the option "--html" from the xsltproc command, the problem is resolved. However I am still not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc a.xslt a.html > b.html
```

UPDATE 2

It seems that the input file is interpreted as ASCII or ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. I have inserted the following header in the input a.html:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
  </head>
```

However the output b.html is still the same.

UPDATE 3

I have update a.xslt to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please notice the different xsl:output line

This creates b.html with the same problem but the first line gives the following html declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Perhaps behind here there is the reason why ASCII or ISO-8859-1 is used to interpret the input file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION

xsltproc picks up the file encoding of HTML input files from the META Content-Type header. When such a header is not present it might assume the file encoding incorrectly and butcher the file while reading it.

I have inserted the following header in the input a.html:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

And I have run the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc --html a.xslt a.html > b.html
```

The xslt a.xslt is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output file b.html is at last as expected:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrd">
      <div class="wrd-id">5</div>
      <div class="wrd-wrd">address</div>
      <div class="wrd-ipa">əˈdres,ˈaˌdres</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. A very helpful answer.

Comment: In fact I have already spotted that there is `--encoding` parameter which allows you to specify the encoding of the input file if the meta information is not present in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was able to fix it with the `--encoding` parameter @Jagger suggests in [xslt transforms utf-8 characters to a different encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247144/xslt-transforms-utf-8-characters-to-a-different-encoding#comment78842283_36372562)

Example (using Yalmar's `a.sh` as a base as my script is more complicated):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc --html --encoding UTF-8 a.xslt a.html > b.html
```